# What’s wrong with the jekyll gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I am trying to update jekyll for a while now but all I got is this Error:

```
localhost:~ MYNAME$ sudo gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
localhost:~ MYNAME$ sudo gem update jekyll
Updating installed gems
Updating jekyll
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::SpecificGemNotFoundException)
   Could not find a valid gem 'jekyll' (= 1.4.2) locally or in a repository
localhost:~ MYNAME$
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

When I’ll try to install jekyll (What isn't really necessary, because I am already working with it) I’ll get this:

```
localhost:~ MYNAME$ sudo gem install jekyll
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'jekyll' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server key exchange B: bad ecpoint (https://aws-eu-cache01.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/jekyll-1.4.2.gemspec.rz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: jekyll
localhost:~ MYNAME$
```

No Clue! I already updated my certificates with `rvm`and `brew` but receive the same errors.

And I already tried to set URL to http like this:

```
localhost:~ MYNAME$ gem update jekyll --source http://rubygems.org
```

Same result!

Comment: Nothing to do with Jekyll, it's a RVM + Openssl + Rubygems issue.

Comment: But how can I fix it?

Comment: See the question I linked to as duplicate, there are several suggestions. Take a look at the highest rated answer first.

Comment: No suggestion from that post work for me. Seems my brew installation is some how f**** up. I now deinstalled brew. Let’s see what will happen. Thanx anyway!

Comment: You can manually download jekyll gem, from ruby gems in then install it from you computer. `wget https://rubygems.org/downloads/jekyll-1.4.2.gem` then `gem install jekyll-1.4.2.gem`. However, the updating the `--system` update the system wide gem's isn't good way, you are able to crush the system. Use `rvm/rbenv` instead.

Comment: Thank you for all your advises! I followed the link by p11y and it work out.